# Re-enter PID 1 namespace

Tags: linux, process, namespace

I'm trying to enter PID namespace that process with PID 1 is in from a process cloned with `CLONE_NEWPID`. I keep getting `Invalid argument` error.

In other words, I clone a child process with `clone()` and `CLONE_NEWPID` flag. After it in the child process I open `/proc/1/ns/pid` for reading and try to execute `setns()` with the descriptor opened above. `setns()` fails with `Invalid argument`.

Full program code: https://gist.github.com/k-popov/ef87076785d8264ac66f

Is that some (security?) mechanism that prevents from entering PID 1's namespace or parent's namespace. I know there is one for User namespace but what about PID one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a security feature, described in the [PID namespace man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pid_namespaces.7.html).

> While processes may freely descend into child PID namespaces (e.g.,
>          using setns(2) with CLONE_NEWPID), they may not move in the other
>          direction.  That is to say, processes may not enter any ancestor
>          namespaces (parent, grandparent, etc.).  Changing PID namespaces is a
>          one way operation.

Comment: Is that true? What if I'm root and use `nsenter -t1 -a` to enter all namespaces of `init`?